# Get rows with IDs retrieved from other table, in the right order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have two tables, `Posts` and `Cache`.

`Cache` tables saves that with Posts should I show. Posts IDs are saved in a column (`PostIDs` in `Cache` table, separated by a comma (`,`).

And this is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts a
WHERE ID IN 
(
  SELECT item FROM Cache AS b
  CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplit(b.postIDs, ',') 
  WHERE ((b.ownerID = 1) AND (b.magID = 8))
)
```

Also `fnSplit` is working correctly.

But the problem is, the order of posts is not correct.

For example, if We have this string in `Cache` : `5,1,9,4,10,3`, I want to get posts from `Posts` with that order. (First row should be the post with ID 5, then 1, then 9, then 4, ...)

But my code returns posts in another order: `1,3,4,5,9,10` (The order of rows in `Posts` table)

What should I do (pure SQL) to get items in the order specified in `Cache` table? (In that example, I want to get posts in this order: `5,1,9,4,10,3`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, this should work (where cacheorder is the field you want to order by)

```
SELECT * FROM Posts a 
     inner join 
     ( 
        SELECT item, cacheorder FROM Cache AS b 
        CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplit(b.postIDs, ',')  
        WHERE ((b.ownerID = 1) AND (b.magID = 8)) 
     ) v
     ON a.ID = v.item
ORDER BY CacheOrder
```

However

- There is no inherent guaranteed order of records - if you want a specific order you have to specify it
- If you're storing postIDs in a comma separated field, your database design is flawed.

Comment: There is not any field named `cacheorder` in my table. I want to order items with the order that is in `b.postIDs` string.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite your fnSplit so it returns an order.

Comment: Isn't there any other way? (Since fnSplit returns rows in the right order)

Comment: And, you said that my database design is flawed. Can you suggest a better database design?

Comment: Yes - Make cache have one row per postID. Then you can add an order field.